# Como modificar o conteúdo de uma raiz usando um ponteiro?

Tags: c, ponteiro

Como modificar o conteúdo de uma raiz usando um ponteiro?

> Escreva um código em C que use uma variável com nome ‘raiz’, tenha o tipo ‘float’ e tenha como valor inicial o número 3.1415.
>
> Neste mesmo código, use outra variável com nome ‘aponta_para_raiz’ que permita armazenar o endereço de memória da  variável ‘raiz’ supracitada.
>
> Por fim, modifique o conteúdo da variável ‘raiz’ por meio da variável ‘aponta_para_raiz’ para que o valor de ‘raiz’ seja 3.141592.
>   No final do código, use printf para imprimir na tela o valor da variável ‘raiz’.

De 3.1415 para 3.141592

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main()
{

  float raiz = 3.1415;
  int *aponta_para_raiz;

  printf(" RAIZ = %f\n", raiz );
  printf (" RAIZ MODIFICADA = %d", *aponta_para_raiz);


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O fato de ser uma raiz é ortogonal, ou seja, não importa para a questão.

Claro que que fazer isto aí é desnecessário, mas entendo que esteja querendo fazer só pra exercitar.

Sempre que for acessar o valor de uma variável que está sendo apontada por outra variável você tem que usar o operador de *dereference*. Este operador é o oposto do operador de `&` que é o "endereço de". Então no seu código você tem que guardar em `aponta_para_raiz` o endereço de `raiz`, portanto  `&raiz`. E depois quando for acessar o valor de raiz terá que fazer `*aponta_para_raiz`. Se não usar este operador está acessando o endereço em si e não o valor que está no endereço.

Perceba que tem dois erros ligados no código. O ponteiro criado é um `int *` que lê-se como "Ponteiro para `int`", mas o que você quer é um ponteiro para `float`. E depois usa `%d` no `printf()` quando o certo é um `%f`.

Se mandar imprimir `aponta_para_raiz` por curiosidade verá o endereço da memória onde está a variável `raiz`. Para isto tem que usar o `%p` no `printf()`. Na execução eu fiz isto, clica e veja lá.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float raiz = 3.1415;
    float *aponta_para_raiz = &raiz;
    *aponta_para_raiz = 3.141592;
    printf("RAIZ = %f\n", raiz);
    printf("RAIZ MODIFICADA = %f", *aponta_para_raiz); //acredito não ser necessário
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/eDWBmJ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/juitnvli-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/ChangeVariable.c).

Comment: printf("RAIZ MODIFICADA = %f", *aponta_para_raiz); //acredito não ser necessário  (Realmente, não é necessário!)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

  float raiz = 3.1415;
  float *aponta_para_raiz;

  aponta_para_raiz = &raiz;

  *aponta_para_raiz = 3.141592;

  printf(" RAIZ = %f\n", raiz );
  printf (" RAIZ MODIFICADA = %f", *aponta_para_raiz);


    return 0;
}
```

O nosso objetivo é fazer com que **aponta_para_raiz** aponte para **raiz** :) assim primeiro devemos criar

```
float *aponta_para_raiz;
```

essa variável guarda um endereço de um float, que no nosso caso será **raiz** ela deve ser do mesmo tipo
do valor apontado, ou seja, devemos criar um ponteiro float para apontarmos para um float.

agora queremos que ela aponte para **raiz** para isso fazemos

```
// aponta_para_raiz recebe a referência de raiz
aponta_para_raiz = &raiz;
```

isso significa que **aponta_para_raiz** recebe a referência de raiz, ou seja, o seu endereço.

e ao fazer

```
*aponta_para_raiz = 3.141592;
```

dizemos ao compilador que quem está apontado por **aponta_para_raiz** recebe 3.141592, ou seja,
**raiz** recebe 3.141592.